# Not able to verify if input field is empty or not after clicking the sumbit button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am basically checking to see if the input field(fullName) is empty or not. If it is empty, then I want to disable the submit button, and forcing the user to add text in the FullName field.

To achieve this scenario, I did the following(code below), but when testing,  I am still able to click the submit button, even if the FullName field is empty. I am not sure, what I am doing wrong with the JavaScript code.

I am doing all of this inside an .htm file.

```js
function checkform(form) {
  if (form.FullName.value == "") {
    alert("Please enter your name!");
    form.FullName.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="" for="FullName">Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input id="FullName" name="FullName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" tabindex="1">
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Where is you `form` tag and when are you firing the `checkform` function?

Comment: @PraneetDixit My question is with the JavaScript not the HTML. The issue is with the JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS is ok. There are some changes -

First, wrap the form content in a `form` with a name attribute of `form`.

Next, fire the `checkform` function on clicking the submit button.

Check the snippet below-

```js
function checkform(form) {
  if (form.FullName.value == "") {
      alert("Please enter your name!");
      form.FullName.focus();
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<div id="Wrapp" class="container">
  <div id="MyName" class="center">
    <button id="btn_MyNamebutton" class="btn btn-namebtn">Sign In</button>
    <form name="form">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="" for="FullName">Name 
          <span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
        <input id="FullName" name="FullName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" tabindex="1">
      </div>
      <!-- Button -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <button id="btn_sumbit" type="submit" class="btn btn-namebtn" onclick="checkform(document.form)">Sign up</button>
        <button id="btn_clear" type="reset" class="btn">Cancel</button> 
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function checkform(form) {
  if (form.FullName.value == "") {
    alert("Please enter your name!");
    form.FullName.focus();
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="Wrapp" class="container">
  <div id="MyName" class="center">
    <button id="btn_MyNamebutton" class="btn btn-namebtn">Sign In</button>
    <fieldset>
      <form name='form' id='form'>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="" for="FullName">Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
          <input id="FullName" name="FullName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" tabindex="1">
        </div>
        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <button id="btn_sumbit" type="button" class="btn btn-namebtn" onclick='checkform(form)'>Sign up</button>
          <button id="btn_clear" type="reset" class="btn">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note:- You have not added form tag and `onclick='checkform(form)'` which created issue in your code.

Comment: I see now! got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are attempting?

Onclick if value of input is empty then you will see alert and button will disable.

EDIT: Included comments in code.

```js
//get FullName input by id
var FullName = document.getElementById("FullName");
//get button by id
var btn_submit = document.getElementById("btn_submit");

function checkform() {
  //if FullName is empty then alert and disable button
  if (FullName.value === "") {
    alert("Please enter your name!");
    btn_submit.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="Wrapp" class="container">
  <div id="MyName" class="center">
    <button id="btn_MyNamebutton" class="btn btn-namebtn">Sign In</button>
    <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="" for="FullName">Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input id="FullName" name="FullName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" tabindex="1">
      </div>
      <!-- Button -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <button onclick="checkform();" id="btn_submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-namebtn">Sign up</button>
        <button id="btn_clear" type="reset" class="btn">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this helps. I had forgotten onClick="checkForm". That's was my issue. Thanks for your help.